# CodeArtifact: download asset using PowerShell

Tags: aws-powershell, aws-codeartifact

I am trying to download an asset from CodeArtifact, in this case it is a zip file.

I know how to do it using AWS CLI but we are a PowerShell shop so I want to use the AWSPowerShell library function.

This is what I have:

```
Get-CAPackageVersionAsset -Asset MyAsset.3.55.98.zip -Domain mydomain -DomainOwner <aws_account_id> -Format generic -Namespace mynamespace -Package MyAsset -PackageVersion 3.55.98 -Repository myrepo
```

This returns an object of type `Amazon.CodeArtifact.Model.GetPackageVersionAssetResponse`. That object has a property `Asset` of type `Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.CachingWrapperStream`.

I have been unable to figure out how to use the returned object to actually download the file.

The AWS CLI equivalent command (`aws codeartifact get-package-version-asset`) has an argument for download path. As far as I can tell, the PowerShell command has no such thing.

How do I actually download the asset using PowerShell?

Comment: Never used that call but the Asset Property of GetPackageVersionAssetReponse() looks like a System.IO.Stream. That could be what you selected, and you could save that to a local file, perhaps? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CodeArtifact/TGetPackageVersionAssetResponse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with the idea of downloading from the stream and got this to work:

```
$buildPackage = Get-CAPackageVersionAsset -Asset MyAsset.3.55.98.zip -Domain mydomain -DomainOwner <aws_account_id> -Format generic -Namespace mynamespace -Package MyAsset -PackageVersion 3.55.98 -Repository myrepo

$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$buildPackage.Asset.CopyTo($ms)
$bytes = $ms.ToArray()
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($DownloadPath, $bytes)
```